# malloc() and realloc() of structures

Tags: c, memory, struct

Can we dynamically allocate memory for structures? Is this a correct procedure to approach a dynamically allocated structures? Please tell me how to `malloc()` and `realloc()` a structure.

newnode is of type struct List * but when start indexing it converts to struct List.How this conversion possible?My insert function accepts only (struct List*) Am I wrong somewhere?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct List {
    char val[20];
};

void insert(struct List *);

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int size = 1;
    struct List *newnode = (struct List *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct List));
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (size <= i) {
            size = size + size;
            newnode = (struct List *)realloc(newnode, size * sizeof(struct List));
        }
        scanf("%s", newnode[i].val);
        insert(newnode[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", newnode[i].val);
    }
    return 0;
}

void insert(struct List *node) {
    printf("%s\n", node->val);
}
```

Comment: Does it compile? -> it doesn't. The handling of `realloc` is wrong, if `realloc` fails you lost the original array too...

Comment: Why `relloc` is wrong what is the right way to implement it?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38213123/10871073 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073

Comment: " Is this a correct procedure" --> missing `free()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your  quick replies....One more question ,newnode is of type struct List * but when start indexing it converts to struct List.How this conversion possible?My insert function accepts only (struct List*) Am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The code works except for 3 problems:

- You do not test for memory allocation failure. Both `malloc()` and `realloc()` will return `NULL` if memory cannot be allocated: you will get undefined behavior when dereferencing `newnode` should this happen.
- to handle the case of `realloc()` failure gracefully, you should store the reallocated pointer to a different variable so you can still access the previous array that has not been deallocated and free it.
- `scanf("%s", newnode[i].val);` is a security flaw: you should limit the number of bytes that can be stored to the destination array with

  ```
  scanf("%19s", newnode[i].val);
  ```
- you do not test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input.
- `insert()` does not *insert* anything.

Here is a modified version with error handling and less confusing names:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Item {
    char val[20];
};

//void insert(struct Item *);

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    int size = 0;
    struct Item *array = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i >= size) {
            int newsize = size ? 1 : size + size;
            struct Item *newarray = realloc(array, sizeof(*array) * size);
            if (newarray == NULL) {
                perror("cannot reallocate the array");
                break;
            }
            size = newsize;
            array = newarray;
        }
        if (scanf("%19s", array[i].val) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "missing input\n");
            break;
        }
        //insert(array[i]);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < i; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i].val);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IDK, perhaps to start interesting conversations like this?  (Social engineering bot)  ;-)

Comment: IAC, I would have used `struct List *newnode = realloc(node, sizeof *node * size);` or even `void *newnode = realloc(node, sizeof *node * size);`.  Many ways are acceptable.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: good suggestion, but to avoid the somewhat confusing combination of unary and binary `*`, I prefer to use redundant parentheses and write `void *newnode = realloc(node, sizeof(*node) * size);`

Comment: it is not the list only the array of structs.

Comment: @P__J__: I agree that the choice of `struct` tag and variable names is quite confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is fine except that you are assigning the return value to your original array pointer. `realloc()` returns `NULL` if it can't resize the memory. You need to assign it to a temporary variable and, if the value is `NULL`, don't overwrite `a`.

The main thing you have to watch out for are pointers, which your `struct` doesn't have. In those cases, the memory pointed to is not part of the allocated array.